# Is there a convenient way to insert blank pdf pages into my pdf?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, pdftk

I have a pdf file `foo.pdf`. I want to create a pdf file `foo-blankbacks.pdf` whose odd pages are the pages of `foo.pdf` and whose even pages are blank. Can this be easily accomplished from the command line?

Comment: Would you be open to LaTeX solutions? Unless you already use LaTeX, it will probably be overkill to install it just for this.

Comment: Yes. In fact, `foo.pdf` was generated by `foo.tex`!

Comment: Oh wow, in that case there are all *sorts* of things you can do, but by going back to the original `foo.tex` file. I don't remember how off the top of my head, but you can relatively easily configure LaTeX to add empty pages. You might want to post a question on [tex.se] with your original LaTeX code and see if they can help.

Comment: This may work using Latex: [Insert a blank page after current](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36880/insert-a-blank-page-after-current-page#36881)

Answer (score 4):

There's an example in the `pdftk` man page that serves as a good starting point:

```
EXAMPLES
   Collate scanned pages
     pdftk A=even.pdf B=odd.pdf shuffle A B output collated.pdf
```

In your case `foo.pdf` is called `even.pdf` and a second pdf called `odd.pdf` is filled with blank odd pages.  The only work left is to count the number of odd pages required.

If you want a quick answer:

```
$ convert xc:none -page Letter blank.pdf
$ pdftk blank.pdf cat 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 output 10blank.pdf
$ pdftk 10blank.pdf cat 1-10 1-10 1-10 1-10 1-10 1-10 1-10 1-10 1-10 1-10  output 100blank.pdf
```

I'm sure there's a *much* neater way to do this... but this will work for the immediate need.

Comment: If I have `blank.pdf` (one blank page), is there a convenient way to make `blank100.pdf` (a pdf with 100 blank pages)?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick this should do it: `gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/dev/stdout $(perl -e 'print "blank.pdf " x 100') > 100blank.pdf`

Comment: @terdon Issuing this command raises the error `GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick oh. I just copy/pasted it on my Arch and it worked fine. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack this with a little script that generates a silly LaTeX file. First, you need to know how many pages you have in your `foo.pdf` and then create the LatEx file with:

```
numberOfPages=100 ## change this to the correct number
echo '\documentclass{article}' > new.tex
echo '\usepackage{pdfpages}' >> new.tex
echo '\begin{document}' >> new.tex
for((i=1;i<=$numberOfPages;i++)); do 
    echo "\includepdf[pages=$i]{foo}"
    echo '\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage'
done >> new.tex
echo '\end{document}' >> new.tex
```

Then, compile it and it should be what you need:

```
pdflatex new.tex
```

That said, it would be much easier to just generate the original `foo.pdf` with extra blank pages, but how to do that would be best asked over at https://tex.stackexchange.com/.